# Updating thunderbird to 102 is not working (version number problem?)

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, thunderbird

I'm using ubuntu 22.04 LTS and have installed thunderbird.

As I'd like to use a more up to date version I added the mozillateam ppa repository (ppa:mozillateam/ppa). Running sudo apt update and upgrade gave me 91.12.0 as most recent version.

Looking at https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/ revealed a 102 version.

apt update shows that it's fetching from mozillateam repository.

So I'd like to ask if there is maybe a problem with version numbering switching from two to three digits and sorting 102 before 91?

Comment: The number of digits in a version number is insignificant.  Is that *really* the question you want to ask? Because that's the question that you asked... I suggest you read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283). If you don't have a very good reason to need a newer version I suggest that you leave it alone and stick with the version that's in repositories.

Comment: Thanks, that was the question, for the time being. It the digits are not the problem then there ist something else mixed up. I'll check.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. As you can see [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages), the PPA contains version 91.12 of Thunderbird (not 102.1) for Ubuntu 22.04. It contains version 102.1 for the yet to be released Ubuntu 22.10.

To get the latest version of Thunderbird in Ubuntu 22.04, you can either use snap

```
sudo snap install thunderbird
```

or flatpak,

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub org.mozilla.Thunderbird
```